# Jenkins Test Trend Graph Not Updating

Tags: jenkins, automated-tests

The company I work for uses Jenkins as their test management software. Very useful, very pleased with it so far. The only trouble is that the Test Result Trend graph hasn't actually updated since Build #28. (We're up to build #54 for this particular suite of automation.)

Is there any way we can force the TRTG to update?

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need a successful build to update the test trend. Check why builds are marked as failures since 28#.

To do this you can click on console output on last build failure.

Comment: We're still getting HTML results, but the trend graph just isn't updating. Perfectly answered why, though.

Thanks!

Comment: There was also an issue where the JUnit was attempting to output to a place that didn't exist.